# Find expected number of distinct pairs from occurrences of elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Two elements are sampled at once from two unknown independent discrete distributions $N$ times, but occurrences of the pairs are not registered, only occurrences of the elements from each distribution:

$$(a_1, a_2,.., a_k), (b_1, b_2, .., b_m), \sum_{i = 1}^k{a_i} = \sum_{i =1}^m{b_i} = N.$$

I want to get an expected number of distinct pairs from the occurrences of elements.

A rough estimate is also acceptable.

Comment: Is there anything you tried to solve this problem that didn't work?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I have no ideas how to approach this. I need a solution to parallelize the software routine efficiently.

Comment: For each pair, find the chance it is chosen at least once and add them up.  By linearity that is the expected number to get.